# Print the genres of the book

Tags: java

This is my code to display the genres of a book. In this code I have to print only the genres of a book. Well there are many more than on genre called SciFi, we have to print one genre of a SciFi. Thanks.

```
public Class Catalogue(){

    private List<Movie> moviesAvailable;

    private List<Movie> moviesRented;
    private List<Genre> genres;
    public Catalogue(){
        moviesAvailable = new LinkedList<Movie>();
        moviesRented = new LinkedList<Movie>();
        genres = new LinkedList<Genre>();
        moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("Matrix",1999,new Genre("SciFi"),3));
        moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("Jurassic Park",1993, new Genre("SciFi"),4));
        moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("The conjuring",1993, new Genre("Horror"),4));

    }
    private getOnlyGenres(){
        System.out.print("The library has the following genres:")
        for(Genre genre:moviesAvailable){
            System.out.print(genre.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You iterate your List moviesAvailable which is a list of Movie, but you expect a genre, the compiler should not tolerate this

Comment: You can use a `Set` instead of a `List`.

Comment: This code has obvious syntax errors. Please post real code, not an approximation. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @vincrichaud could you do that for me please if you don't mind.

Comment: @PramishLuitel do what ? your job ? nop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working examples with some extra Lists removed:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Movie> moviesAvailable;

        moviesAvailable = new LinkedList<Movie>();

        moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("Matrix",1999,new Genre("SciFi"),3));
        moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("Jurassic Park",1993, new Genre("SciFi"),4));
        moviesAvailable.add(new Movie("The conjuring",1993, new Genre("Horror"),4));

        moviesAvailable.stream().map(movie -> movie.getGenre().getName()).distinct().forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}

class Genre {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Genre (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

class Movie {
    private String name;
    private int year;
    private Genre genre;
    private int whatever;

    public Genre getGenre()
    {
        return this.genre;
    }

    public Movie (String name, int year, Genre genre, int whatever) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.whatever = whatever;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this print "SciFi" twice?

Comment: @Pavel M I have same exactly same code but it didn't delete any duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change several things:

1. Add a `getGenre()` method to your `Movie` class if it doesn't have one.
2. When you iterate over your list of movies, you get a `Movie` object, not a `Genre`. This means you need to change:

   ```
   for(Genre genre:moviesAvailable){
   ```

   to

   ```
   for(Movie movie : moviesAvailable){
   ```
3. Now get the `Genre` from each `Movie` and add it to a `Set` instead of a `List`.

Comment: can't we add on the list coz Set can't be accepted by my school database so

Comment: @PramishLuitel A `Set` will remove duplicates for you automatically. If you aren't allowed to use it, then you will need to write the code to remove duplicates yourself.